# How to upload a file from local path?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my problem, I would like to upload a file from a local path but i can't change input file value because it is impossible

The classical code of simple file upload :

**HTML-code:**

```
<input id="file" type="file" />
<progress id="progress"></progress>
```

**JavaScript-code:**

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file'),
    progress = document.querySelector('#progress');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'upload.html');

    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        progress.value = e.loaded;
        progress.max = e.total;
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        alert('Upload terminé !');
    }, false);

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file',         fileInput.files[0]);

    xhr.send(form);

  }, false);
```

How can we change it?

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean you want to know how to handle the upload request via AJAX?

Comment: I mean, select a file via JavaScript with a path that I know and upload the file with xhr request but i don't know how tout select a file with a path. Thanks un advance

Comment: Are you asking how to access the value of your `<input>`?

Comment: On @PM77-1 question: It is forbidden to retrieve the full path to a file due to security policies by modern browsers. A malicious coder could use this to retrieve information about your machine.

Comment: It is my problème! :)

Comment: @DuckDucky what do you mean with your comment?

Comment: I say that my problem is what you say :) I want tout find a way to upload a file with a knowing path

Comment: There is no way otherwise you could trick users into uploading what ever you want.

Comment: Maybe we can transform a path on an object file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with pure JS. Modern browsers prevent you from direct work with the user's filesystem due to obvious insecurity. However, you can try to do it using Flash, ActiveX, Silverlight and so on.